# Value Pass to the variable in java

Tags: java

I have following code.I can't understand it's behavior about passing values.

```
class Box{

    int length=5;
    int height=5;
    int width=10;

    void volume(){
        int volume;
        volume=length*height*width;

        System.out.println(volume);
    }

}

public class DemoBox {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Box ob=new Box();
        ob.length=10;
        ob.height=10;
        ob.width=10;

        ob.volume();
    }
}
```

This provided output as 1000. Why it is not 250? How values assign to the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the values to length, height, and width in the DemoBox class. Therefore, calling the object ob.volume() assigns the new values, and makes the old values moot.

You can use the principle of function Overloading and define two different functions

```
int volume ()
{return length*height*width;
}

int volume(int length, int height, int width)

{return length*height*width; }
```

when calling the functions from DemoBox

```
int returnedvalue = volume () //returns 2500
int returnedvalue = volume (10,10,10); //returns 1000
```

Comment: Thanks @tanveer..I got it.I'm new for the java. So I have to learn more :)

Answer (score 1):

Its returning 1000 because you are resetting the value of length width and height with 10.

```
ob.length=10;
ob.height=10;
ob.width=10;
```

So 10*10*10 =1000

Pass those values during invocation of volume method :

```
ob.volume(5,10,5);
```

Body of volume() method :

```
void volume(int length, int width, int height){
    int volume=length*height*width;

    System.out.println(volume);
       }

     }
```

Comment: This answers the question, but changing the `volume` method like this would defeat the purpose of having the `Box` class in the first place.

Comment: Agreed. In that case one constructor needs to be declared like :

`Box(int length,int width, int height) {

this.length = length;
this.width = width;
this.height = height;

}`

And volume method would be like :

`public int volume( ) {

return length*height*width;
}`